# Multi-player Random Number Game Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a random MultiPlayer guessing game on Java and I'm having trouble with it. The code below is what I have so far. I need to insert code that will prompt the user to input how many people are playing. Once they do that and start guessing, the program should take guesses from each player until one guesses it correctly, in that case, that player will then be skipped until the rest of the players guess their numbers as well. The program assigns each user their own unique number. (Example: There are three players. Player one guesses 1. That's too low. Player two guesses 4. That's correct! Player three guesses 4. That's too high. Player one guesses 2. That's correct! Player three guesses 3. That's correct! ...etc)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class MultiRandGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int NumGuess = rand.nextInt(101);
        int NumTries = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int guess;
        boolean Game = false;

        while (Game == false) {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and a 100: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            NumTries++;

            if (guess == NumGuess) {
                Game = true;
            }

            else if (guess < NumGuess) {
                System.out.println("Too low!");

            }

            else if (guess > NumGuess) {
                System.out.println("Too high!");

            }
        }

        System.out.println("You got it!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + NumGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + NumTries + " tries!");

    }
}
```

Comment: How do multiple users get chance...in a queue?

Comment: Yes; it would be a consecutive queue.. one user guesses, then the next, if that user gets it correctly, then they are skipped until every player guesses correctly and the game is over

Comment: Assuming this is all in a command window, does everyone get a unique number? If one person guesses correctly, everyone will get it.

Comment: Everyone gets a unique number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easier to understand code if you read about naming conventions. `Game` to `game`, `NumGuess` to `numGuess` and so on. Here is a place to [read about it.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

As for multiple people playing a game this simple, you could just have a for loop through each guess, saving the player number who guessed correctly. You also need to have arrays for which player has guess correctly and what their number to guess is.

```
int guess = 0;
int playerCount = 2;
//boolean[] won = new boolean[playerCount];
int[] numbers = new int[playerCount];

for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(101);

System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 100.");
while (game == false) {
    for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; players++) {
        System.out.print("Player #"+player+" guess: ");
        guess = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        //if (won[player] == false) {
            if (guess == numbers[player]) {
                //won[player] = true;
                game = true;
                System.out.println("Player #" + player + ": Correct!");
                break;
            } else if (guess < numGuess) {
                System.out.println("Player #" + player + ": Too low!");
            } else if (guess > numGuess) {
                System.out.println("Player #" + player + ": Too high!");
            }
        //}

    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    //  if (won[i] == true)
    //      game = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a little, but once the correct guess is guessed it loops back to player one again. It doesn't say "correct" and then switches to player 2.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Once someone guesses correctly, the other players will still guess until they are correct too.

Comment: I might have been a little unclear in my initial post, I'm sorry. I mean that when player one guesses the number, "correct" doesn't display, and it doesn't switch to player 2.

Comment: That's different from what you said before. Once one player guesses correctly the game ends?

Comment: @OFakos You weren't "a little unclear" in your initial post. Your description of the desired behavior is quite clear. But your comment here contradicts it. Please edit the question to make it say what you want it to say.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I edited my initial posting. @Matthew Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I've edited my answer to what it originally was. It breaks out of the player loop and `game = true` ending the game.